# Powershell command providing incomplete list

Tags: powershell

This PS command is only returning 10 out of 12 groups that the user is member of.  Anyone know why that will be?

```
Get-ADUser -Identity username -Properties memberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberOf > C:\user.csv
```

Comment: Are any of the missing group memberships nested groups?  Also, you won't see the Primary Group (usually Domain Users) from `Get-ADUser`.

Comment: Okay so domain users is accounted for and this link showed why http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/44ecf833-e644-411b-9ef0-fa56b7fb4e26/domain-users-not-showing-up-in-memberof.  Running the command second time brought up 11 groups so its possible it needed to update.  I think we are good, thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able. This will ensure the question is not orphaned as open.

Answer (score 0):

To get the complete list i would use:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Idendtity username | Select-Object name | Export-CSV c:\membership.csv
```